# Como usar um "AND" com o :not do CSS?

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte HTML e seletor CSS:

```css
main>*:not(.not-me) {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Azul!</p>
  <p class="not-me">Eu não!</p>
  <span>Eu também não!</span>
  <p>Azul!</p>
</main>
```

Mas eu não quero selecionar elementos que forem `span`. Para isso, eu posso usar o `:not(span)`, mas, eu quero combinar com o seletor acima. Então, tentei com isso:

```css
main>*:not(.not-me),main>*:not(span) { /* <--- tentei combinar com , */
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Azul!</p>
  <p class="not-me">Eu não!</p>
  <span>Eu também não!</span>
  <p>Azul!</p>
</main>
```

Mas o resultado é que todos os elementos foram afetados. Acredito que é porque o separador `,` é um `seletor OU seletor`.

Eu posso fazer um seletor de forma que exclua dois ou mais seletores com o `:not` sem ter que declarar uma substituição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível concatenar o `:not` várias vezes, como por exemplo:

```css
seletor:not(seletor):not(seletor):not(...)... {}
```

```css
main>*:not(.not-me):not(span) {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Azul!</p>
  <p class="not-me">Eu não!</p>
  <span>Eu também não!</span>
  <p>Azul!</p>
</main>
```

Dessa forma, ele irá funcionar da forma `AND NOT` para todos os seletores especificados.

Felizmente, o `:not` [é suportado](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anot) na maioria dos navegadores modernos de hoje.